# Is it possible to create a modal or show a prompt message when the user clicks the back button to prevent automatic logout?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that will ask password of the user if he really wants to leave the page, the reason i will do this because if the user leave, their account will be automatically logging out. It will affect to their history and performance.

I've come up to;

- Create a modal and will popup if user click back button
  [image: back button(GOOGLE)]
- Show prompt message

I don't know if these two is possible..

here's what i have tried so far

```
window.onbeforeunload = (event) => {
       let userpassword = prompt("Please confirm your credentials.");
       if (userpassword !== '44344') {
           event.preventDefault()
       }
}
```

**I don't want to prevent** the user to **automatically logout**, (I can't update my title, because it is the AI suggested, i need to change it but it gives error so... yeah)

They are free to leave the page it is just that they need to confirm that they're the one who click the back button
Any logic will be accepted, comment, suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: I can think of a hack with `history.pushState`, but why does going back log the user out? Are you able to fix that instead?

Answer (score 2):

I wish navigation events (backward/forward) get added some time. So far this is something in work. Until that following [workaround](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming) can be used to detect browser back button clicks.

```
const isBackButtonClicked = performance && performance.getEntriesByType( 'navigation' ).map( nav => nav.type ).includes( 'back_forward' )
```